# Filter numbers in one column based on whether they are higher than in another column

Tags: google-sheets

How to filter numerical data in column B based on whether or not the number is higher than the number in column A?

Answer (score 1):

After turning on filtering (Data -> Filter in the menu), choose in filter settings "filter by condition", then "custom formula", and use the formula

```
=A2>B2
```

[image: filter]

---

The above describes in-place filtering. Another approach to filtering data in Sheets is to create another list of numbers elsewhere in the sheet, with a formula such as

```
=filter(A2:A, A2:A > B2:B)
```

See [filter formula documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en).